# estimation of sum over primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The problem is this: I have read that if i have a function $f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ and we are interested in estimation of the sum $V(x)=\sum_{p<x} f(p)$ where $p$ runs on primes numbers then is equivalent to estimate $S(x)=\sum_{n<x} f(n)\Lambda(n)$ (where $\Lambda(n)$ is the [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function)). I don't see why this holds.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific about your own thoughts.  Are you aware that this is more of a principle rather than a formal equivalence?  The right question is not so much "why does this hold?" as it is "under what conditions is this feasible?"

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct as stated, if I understand correctly. The von Mangoldt function equals $\log(p)$ for primes and prime powers, and is zero otherwise. The logarithm may not disappear. The theorems of Mertens  are a good example of what is true: 
$$
\sum_{p\le x}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=\log(x)+O(1)=\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n}.
$$
This is for example used (and refined) for the proof of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: "Typically" may be a bit too strong: if, unlike the above example, the weight $f(n)$ is increasing with $n$, then one benefits from the fact that $\Lambda(p)$ is asymptotically equal to $\log x$ for all but a vanishing proportion of $p \le x$.

Comment: @ErickWong: yes, you are right, I changed it. I find it difficult to formulate, because it is not entirely clear to me what "equivalence" here means.

Comment: Completely agree :).